Fitting a time domain function to frequency domain experimental data
I have an experimental dataset in frequency domain (complex dielectric constant data (K)as a function of frequency of applied signal).
I want to fit it with a function, which is (exponential form) in time domain. The problem is that Fourier transform of this function is not an analytical but remains in the form of an Integral.
How can I fit this time domain function to frequency domain data? Will appreciate any suggestion.
Thanks
PS: The time domain function to be fitted is:
K = A*Exp[-(t/tau)^beta]
The data (freq, K-real, K-imag) is:
{{0.1, 4131.91, 714.636}, {0.12, 4035.69, 724.511}, {0.144, 3936.22,
728.827}, {0.1728, 3835.88, 727.117}, {0.20736, 3735.51,
719.962}, {0.248832, 3631.18, 707.49}, {0.298598, 3534.76,
690.704}, {0.358318, 3442.21, 667.021}, {0.429982, 3354.25,
639.345}, {0.515978, 3271.73, 607.131}, {0.619174, 3195.21,
571.552}, {0.743008, 3125.9, 532.895}, {0.89161, 3065.19,
500.183}, {1.06993, 3008.94, 459.812}, {1.28392, 2958.91,
419.282}, {1.5407, 2915.92, 380.117}, {1.84884, 2877.19,
343.047}, {2.21861, 2844.79, 308.449}, {2.66233, 2825.69,
280.749}, {3.1948, 2801.7, 250.42}, {3.83376, 2779.65,
224.961}, {4.60051, 2762.14, 200.168}, {5.52061, 2746.99,
176.574}, {6.62474, 2732.67, 159.155}, {7.94969, 2719.87,
142.078}, {9.53962, 2710.76, 126.551}, {11.4475, 2701.41,
112.88}, {13.7371, 2693.43, 100.395}, {16.4845, 2686.34,
89.8407}, {19.7814, 2679.68, 80.5511}, {23.7376, 2674,
72.3447}, {28.4852, 2668.79, 64.8037}, {34.1822, 2664.08,
58.2538}, {41.0186, 2659.82, 52.4393}, {49.2224, 2655.95,
47.3832}, {59.0668, 2652.31, 42.6212}, {70.8802, 2649.05,
38.5366}, {85.0562, 2646.21, 34.8901}, {102.067, 2643.56,
31.6184}, {122.481, 2641.19, 28.6957}, {146.977, 2638.75,
26.1751}, {176.373, 2636.8, 23.8408}, {211.647, 2634.88,
21.7709}, {253.977, 2633.19, 19.9374}, {304.772, 2631.61,
18.2808}, {365.726, 2630.14, 16.8381}, {438.871, 2628.78,
15.5121}, {526.646, 2627.53, 14.1973}, {631.975, 2626.44,
13.1215}, {758.37, 2625.4, 12.1747}, {910.044, 2624.37,
11.2984}, {1092.05, 2623.43, 10.5113}, {1310.46, 2622.57,
9.80331}, {1572.56, 2621.35, 9.20985}, {1887.07, 2620.01,
8.60355}, {2264.48, 2620.08, 8.08702}, {2717.38, 2619.19,
7.58539}, {3260.85, 2618.12, 7.15513}, {3913.02, 2618.06,
6.7555}, {4695.63, 2617.26, 6.34925}, {5634.75, 2616.68,
5.8449}, {6761.7, 2616.02, 5.53646}, {8114.04, 2615.32,
5.24601}, {9736.85, 2614.43, 4.98798}, {11684.2, 2614.56,
4.71664}, {14021.1, 2614, 4.53993}, {16825.3, 2613.29,
4.32418}, {20190.3, 2613.39, 4.12453}, {24228.4, 2612.89,
3.95587}, {29074.1, 2612.34, 3.82272}, {34888.9, 2612.45,
3.65205}, {41866.7, 2612.04, 3.52477}, {50240, 2611.95, 2.88082}};
A, tau and beta are the three parameters to be determined.

I think we need to see a bit more. What are the functions you are working with? What does your frequency domain data look like?  As one thought can you take a numerical inverse Fourier transform to get the experimental data back into the time domain and then do your fitting in the time domain?

i have modified the original post to include the time domain function and frequency domain experimental data. Thanks

Please format so that we can copy and paste into Mathematica. The frequency domain data is real. Usually frequency domain data is complex. Are you giving the modulus of a complex function? If so information is missing. Do you have approximate values of the the unknown parameters?

The fourier transform of a function consists of frequency and phase, or together, a complex number. Without the phase you can not reconstruct the original function

The question isn't clear. You wrote : "real part of it". Real part of what ?. Also  you wrote : "frequency vs K'. What is K ? There is no K in your equation  A*Exp[-(t/tau)^beta]. What is "frequency"? There is no frequency in the equation. Downvote(-1).

There are some symmetry conditions that a retarded (i.e. physical) $\epsilon^R$ should fulfil. For instance 1) $\epsilon^R(-\omega)=[\epsilon^R(\omega)]^*$. This means $\textrm{Im}\epsilon^R(0)=0$. This is not the case with your data.  2) Also, the high frequency limit $\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon^R(\omega)=1$ is not fulfilled.

Trying to understand your data better: it looks like you have permittivity measurements of some medium of interest.  Are the measurements relative? or absolute?  Are the frequencies given in hertz or radians per sec?  A permittivity measurement is typically of the form  K(ω) =  K'(ω) -i K''(ω), where K'(ω) is the dielectric constant at ω, K''(ω) is the dielectric loss factor (related to the loss tangent).

Do you really need the parameter beta? If so, can you assume beta is positive real or not?

Yes, it is relative permittivity vs. frequency (Hz) data. K-imag in this table is imaginary part of relative permittivity, not the loss factor.

beta is an important parameter; data cannot be fitted correctly if it is set to be 1. Its value is real positive, theoretically it should lie between 0 and 1.

You said beta is a real. But it seems you have no good fitting under this assumption

The reason is as follows: K=A*exp[- (t/tau)^beta] means Log[K]=Log[A] - C t^beta with C=(1/tau)^beta. Thus, if t varies along real interval, the data points Log[K] must move on a straight line in the complex plane. But ComplexListPlot[(#[[2]]+I #[[3]])&/@data] shows that Log[K]'s lie on a curve.

I agree with @A. Kato in the comments that there is no good fit under your assumptions about the function.
I wrote some code to perform the fitting, where the loss used is the relative error of the real and imaginary parts of K. (Of course, the absolute difference of K could also be used, but the results would be quite different)
data = {{0.1, 4131.91, 714.636}, {0.12, 4035.69, 724.511}, {0.144, 
    3936.22, 728.827}, {0.1728, 3835.88, 727.117}, {0.20736, 3735.51, 
    719.962}, {0.248832, 3631.18, 707.49}, {0.298598, 3534.76, 
    690.704}, {0.358318, 3442.21, 667.021}, {0.429982, 3354.25, 
    639.345}, {0.515978, 3271.73, 607.131}, {0.619174, 3195.21, 
    571.552}, {0.743008, 3125.9, 532.895}, {0.89161, 3065.19, 
    500.183}, {1.06993, 3008.94, 459.812}, {1.28392, 2958.91, 
    419.282}, {1.5407, 2915.92, 380.117}, {1.84884, 2877.19, 
    343.047}, {2.21861, 2844.79, 308.449}, {2.66233, 2825.69, 
    280.749}, {3.1948, 2801.7, 250.42}, {3.83376, 2779.65, 
    224.961}, {4.60051, 2762.14, 200.168}, {5.52061, 2746.99, 
    176.574}, {6.62474, 2732.67, 159.155}, {7.94969, 2719.87, 
    142.078}, {9.53962, 2710.76, 126.551}, {11.4475, 2701.41, 
    112.88}, {13.7371, 2693.43, 100.395}, {16.4845, 2686.34, 
    89.8407}, {19.7814, 2679.68, 80.5511}, {23.7376, 2674, 
    72.3447}, {28.4852, 2668.79, 64.8037}, {34.1822, 2664.08, 
    58.2538}, {41.0186, 2659.82, 52.4393}, {49.2224, 2655.95, 
    47.3832}, {59.0668, 2652.31, 42.6212}, {70.8802, 2649.05, 
    38.5366}, {85.0562, 2646.21, 34.8901}, {102.067, 2643.56, 
    31.6184}, {122.481, 2641.19, 28.6957}, {146.977, 2638.75, 
    26.1751}, {176.373, 2636.8, 23.8408}, {211.647, 2634.88, 
    21.7709}, {253.977, 2633.19, 19.9374}, {304.772, 2631.61, 
    18.2808}, {365.726, 2630.14, 16.8381}, {438.871, 2628.78, 
    15.5121}, {526.646, 2627.53, 14.1973}, {631.975, 2626.44, 
    13.1215}, {758.37, 2625.4, 12.1747}, {910.044, 2624.37, 
    11.2984}, {1092.05, 2623.43, 10.5113}, {1310.46, 2622.57, 
    9.80331}, {1572.56, 2621.35, 9.20985}, {1887.07, 2620.01, 
    8.60355}, {2264.48, 2620.08, 8.08702}, {2717.38, 2619.19, 
    7.58539}, {3260.85, 2618.12, 7.15513}, {3913.02, 2618.06, 
    6.7555}, {4695.63, 2617.26, 6.34925}, {5634.75, 2616.68, 
    5.8449}, {6761.7, 2616.02, 5.53646}, {8114.04, 2615.32, 
    5.24601}, {9736.85, 2614.43, 4.98798}, {11684.2, 2614.56, 
    4.71664}, {14021.1, 2614, 4.53993}, {16825.3, 2613.29, 
    4.32418}, {20190.3, 2613.39, 4.12453}, {24228.4, 2612.89, 
    3.95587}, {29074.1, 2612.34, 3.82272}, {34888.9, 2612.45, 
    3.65205}, {41866.7, 2612.04, 3.52477}, {50240, 2611.95, 
    2.88082}};
k[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, \[Tau]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ] := 
 1/\[Omega] NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(t/(\[Omega]  \[Tau]))^\[Beta]] Exp[I  t], {t, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 15]
loss[A_, \[Tau]_, \[Beta]_] := Module[{ks, kre, kim, l},
  ks = A  Table[
     k[data[[i, 1]], \[Tau], \[Beta]], {i, 1, data // Length}];
  kre = Table[Re[ks[[i]]]/data[[i, 2]] - 1, {i, 1, data // Length}];
  kim = Table[Im[ks[[i]]]/data[[i, 3]] - 1, {i, 1, data // Length}];
  l = Flatten[{kre, kim}];
  l . l
  (*Norm[data[[;;,2]]+data[[;;,3]]\[ImaginaryI]-ks]^2*)
  ]
A0 = 227469.2676431593`;
\[Tau]0 = 8.08475175661025`*^-9;
\[Beta]0 = 0.10141828009531231`;
FindMinimum[{loss[
   A, \[Tau], \[Beta]]}, {{\[Tau], \[Tau]0}, {\[Beta], \[Beta]0}, {A, 
   A0}}, StepMonitor :> Print[{A, \[Tau], \[Beta]}], 
 PrecisionGoal -> 3]

(*{74.00852320920657`,{\[Tau]\[Rule]8.08475175661099`*^-9,\[Beta]\
\[Rule]0.10141828009532008`,A\[Rule]227469.26764298117`}}*)

The following code can be used to visualize the fitting results, where the red dots are the original data and the blue dots are the fitted results.
datafit = 
  Table[{data[[i, 1]], 
    A0  k[data[[i, 1]], \[Tau]0, \[Beta]r0, \[Beta]i0]}, {i, 1, 73}];
Show[{ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, PlotHighlighting -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 4200}}],
  ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]] // Re} & /@ datafit, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None]}]
Show[{ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ data, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, PlotHighlighting -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 750}}],
  ListPlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]] // Im} & /@ datafit, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None]}]



From the plot, we can see that as the frequency increases, the real part of K should approach 0, but your data does not seem to satisfy this.
